# ffprobe fake file safety/mime content checking

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

Anyone know if ffprobe is safe to use as a method to check the content of a video? I want to determine if someone renames an exe to mp4 or some other video mime and I run ffprobe on it, would the file execute or fail safely without executing the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffprobe should not execute content unless DirectDraw filter would do it itself (which is rather weird thing to think of).

Yet, AFAIK, ffprobe doesnt't produce nice MIME information, especially for not-multimedia-files. format_name/format_long_name are not very good.

For what you're looking for, the best approach is content sniffing described at https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/

I have found that link in this SO question: [MIME type for transcoded stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985953/mime-type-for-transcoded-stream)